# Is it possible to edit indices in equations in Word 2019?

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor, microsoft-word-2019

I am editing an equation in Word 2019, I have an expression with just lower index f_t:

[image]

but I want to also add an upper index to the "f_t" symbol too. I am trying to do it with the equation index tool the same way as when I was adding the lower index to the "f" symbol:

[image]

but it doesn't change the existing indices of the "f" symbol, it only adds something new. It is frustrating, because that would mean just delete current lower index and start with the indices completely again. Is it possible to somehow just edit a configuration of indices for an existing symbol, which already has some index?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rreIi.png)?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio yes

Comment: @Hannu that's what I am trying to do, but I wasn't able to convice Word to *modify* it... all Word did is that he's adding another empty symbol with both sub&super script..

Answer (score 0):

One methid you can use without deleting the function and the subscript is to change the equation from professional to linear, type the superscript, then changing the equation back to professional. Optionally, you can right-click on the function and align the scripts vertically. See example on the image on the left.

If you want the superscript to also have its own subscript, do as shown on the image on the right.

[image]
[image]